# JFugue - Pattern Output of MIDI file clarification

Tags: java, midi, jfugue, javax.sound.midi

so I've been experimenting with JFugue a little bit and I've become truly interested in the output in readable human form. One thing I see many times is, before the chords, there are a bunch of groups of characters such as **"V1 :CE(X,X)"** and, from what I gathered, V indicates a track, but can't decipher what the :CE means. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JFugue, :CE is a Controller Event (or Control Change Event), a type of MIDI event, and the two numbers are the controller number and the controller value.

Here is a list of MIDI controller numbers, and what the values mean: https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/table-3-control-change-messages-data-bytes-2

Comment: Thank you so much, David! By the way, awesome creation! When outputing the pattern of the midi, this values don't affect how the music is played do they?

Comment: It depends on what the event is, and how the synthesizer uses the event. For example, if the event is a "soft pedal" event, it would mean that the next notes should be played more softly, but that would only matter if the synthesizer supports that kind of play. The controller events would not change the actual notes being generated, and instrument changes are through a different event (JFugue would represent these as capital I followed by a number). For the most part, you're generally safe ignoring them.